# having trouble using a constant in PHP mail() function

Tags: php, constants

I've read the php.net documentation on both constants and the mail() function, but I still am not able to resolve my current problem.

I am trying to build a registration script that, when everything on the form is correct and checks through some regular expressions, adds the user to the database and does 2 things: displays a thank you page, and emails the email address provided a thank you note.

```
 if(empty($reg_errors)) {
        $q = "SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE email = '$e' OR username = '$u'"; //the mysql query to check for dupe emails/users
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
        if($rows==0) {                                 // no dupes of email or user, so let's add them into the DB!
            $q = "INSERT INTO users(username,email,pass,first_name,last_name,date_expires) VALUES('$u','$e','".get_password_hash($p)."','$fn','$ln',ADDDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            //asks DB if a new row was created, and if so, thanks user for registration on the site & sends an email to their email.
            //if query doesnt work, an error is triggered
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)==1) {
                echo '<h3>Thanks!</h3><p>Thank you for registering! You may now log in and access the site\'s content.</p>';
                $body = "Thanks for registering at Knowledge is Power. We greatly appreciate your interest in our services.\n\n";
                mail($_POST['email'],'Registration Confirmation for Knowledge is Power',$body, 'From:DEVEMAIL');
                include('./includes/footer.inc.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                trigger_error("You could not be registered due to a system error. W apologize for any inconvenience.");
            }
        }
```

I set up the DEVEMAIL constant in my config.inc.php file like so:

`define('DEVEMAIL','something@thisplace.com');`

So far, in my testing of this script, it adds the users to the DB and displays the thank you message, but when it sends the thank you email, it's from my generic host email address, and not the email I set up for the constant. Am i formatting the constant in the mail() function incorrectly? Any thanks would be greatly appreciated.

edit: mail server is configured, and looking into creating prepared statements. thanks much for the helpful suggestions.

Comment: Do you have an mail server configured?

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection. And please remove your email address to prevent email harvesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want

```
'From:'.DEVEMAIL
```

Constants do not work inside the quotes

Comment: Just for clarification... if you put a constant in a quote.. PHP will treat it as a string, not a defined constant